# Getting error in this line `Cannot use namespace 'DataTypes' as a type.ts(2709)`

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, sequelize-auto

I used the below configuration to generate models

```
const auto = new SequelizeAuto(
process.env.DB_NAME,
process.env.DB_USER,
process.env.DB_PASS,
{
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  typescript: true,
  camelCaseForFileName: true,
  directory: './src/data/entity'
})
auto.run();
```

But i'm getting error on Models generated `Cannot use namespace 'DataTypes' as a type.ts(2709)`

[image: Error Message]

FYR i also raised an issue GitHub repository: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/384

Comment: This doesn't seem like how you should be using Sequelize with Typescript... Please check here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript

Comment: i'm using `sequelize-auto` package to generate models, but these are giving errors

i checked the link, but i want to generate the models

Comment: Current version (0.7.5) of `sequelize-auto` generates TypeScript according to the guidance in the Sequelize manual.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, changing the auto-generated code from

```
module.exports =  (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: DataTypes)
```

to

```
module.exports =  (sequelize: Sequelize, dataTypes: typeof DataTypes)
```

resolved that error.

Comment: thanks for the update. I have updated my plugin to latest version for both sequelize & sequelize-auto, Latest version of sequelize-auto has more options than earlier